# Unable to create Apple Music JWT token

Tags: python, apple-musickit

I am trying to generate Apple Music JWT token.

I have valid keyId, teamId and .p8 file + I have installed latest version of pyjwt & cryptography.

When I am trying to execute `python music_token.py` I am receiving following error.

(Downloaded music_token.py script for [here](https://github.com/pelauimagineering/apple-music-token-generator))

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "music_token.py", line 33, in <module>
    token = jwt.encode(payload, secret, algorithm=alg, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 56, in encode
    json_payload, key, algorithm, headers, json_encoder
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 102, in encode
    key = alg_obj.prepare_key(key)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/jwt/algorithms.py", line 351, in prepare_key
    key = load_pem_private_key(key, password=None, backend=default_backend())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py", line 20, in load_pem_private_key
    return backend.load_pem_private_key(data, password)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1015, in load_pem_private_key
    password,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1234, in _load_key
    self._handle_key_loading_error()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 1292, in _handle_key_loading_error
    raise ValueError("Could not deserialize key data.")
ValueError: Could not deserialize key data.
```

Can someone please point me in correct direction If I am doing something wrong here?

I tried searching on google and it hints that there could be some problem with installed version `jwt` but I have installed latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when copy paste the private key to music_token.py.
But it worked when I did this instead of secret = "".

```
APNS_AUTH_KEY = './APNsAuthKey_SP7C6832EZ.p8'
f = open(APNS_AUTH_KEY)
secret = f.read()
```